# Extracting dynamic email address from website using scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Email address is generated passively and selector cannot locate this even there is no api request.
I have been doing web scraping for over two years now and this issue comes up every now and then, mostly i solve this by loading a page with selenium and parsing the response but this time i have to stick to scrapy(no splash) only.

I have noticed that once i fetch the link in `scrapy shell` and view response i can see email but selector cannot locate the email.

So far i have been able to locate the javascript request generating the email but i cannot figure out how to reverse engineer it with scrapy.

Here is the link to one of websites of similar examples. Any help is appreciated

[THE WEBSITE](https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/health-and-medicine/about-us/people/lisa-wood)

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like email in this case is obfuscated and later deobfuscated in javascript. Since you scraper doesn't execute javascript you see only obfuscated email.

If you take a look at page source and ctrl+f "email":

[image]

You can see email's obfuscated value.
Now it's up to you to figure out how to deobfuscated. Generally you'd go through websites javascript code and find how email is obfuscated and reverse engineer that. This is a bit of out of scope of this question but obfuscation code in this cases does:

- replace `@` with `//`
- replace `.` with `/`
- reverses the whole string

So if we can reverse that in python:

```
value = "ku/ca/retsacnal//eromhsa/l"
value = value[::-1]
value = value.replace(r"//", "@").replace(r"/", ".")
```

which turns into exactly what we see on the website: `l.ashmore@lancaster.ac.uk` !

Comment: This is a great answer and solves this particular problem and you are no doubt a genius but this issue keeps coming up i do solve couple of similar problems but can you point me to where i can learn or get a hint about how to reverse that in javascript? i tried executing javascript in python but it has so many dependences  within html and i am also not good with js.

Comment: @AssadAli don't sweat it too much - reverse engineering is all about experience! Unfortunately I don't have any particular resource recommendations. Generally you should start by getting to know your browsers developer tools - there you can find all of the javascript the website uses and observe it's behavior real time. I'm working on some articles on this subject on my free web-scraping blog (check my profile) for this very reason :)